# Why is there a deadlock with flush?

Tags: http, go, server

I am a beginner in Golang. I have written simple code for HTTP handler that writes to stream and flushes manually often (I do not want the client to receive everything at once).

I expect the line output to be a permutation of (1 to 10, and 10 to 100, counting by 10s):

```
1
10
20
2
3
30
4
40
50
60
5
6
70
7
80
8
9
90
100
10
```

`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    flusher, _ := w.(http.Flusher)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func(){
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i)
            flusher.Flush()
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func(){
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i * 10)
            flusher.Flush()
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The actual output is:

```
10
1
2
20
```

or (the zero is not a typo)

```
10
1
2
20
0
2
```

or (10 is repeated and the HTTP headers are showing???)

```
10
1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 00:12:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
3
10
10
```

The stream ends after outputting the lines. Why am I not getting the expected output and how do I fix it?

It works fine if I use just one of the two anonymous goroutines. Please ignore the use of `time.Sleep`.

Comment: The program has a data race on the response writer. Use a mutex to ensure that response writer methods are not called concurrently,

Comment: If a type isn't explicitly documented to be safe for concurrent use you should automatically assume it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the data race (and this is good practice for code with threads in it, even if it isn't acting "weird") try `go run -race main.go`.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `Fprintf` and `Flush()` with a mutex:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mu := sync.Mutex{}
    flusher, _ := w.(http.Flusher)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func(){
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i)
            flusher.Flush()
            mu.Unlock()
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func(){
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", i * 10)
            flusher.Flush()
            mu.Unlock()
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```